# Android picture: "Share to" → "Show on map"

Tags: android, images, maps, exif, geo-location

Sometimes I want to see where I took a picture.

- For instance, it was a good restaurant and I am trying to find it again.
- Or I want to see how an interesting building I shot a picture of looks from above.
- Or I want to quickly check whether the picture is correctly geotagged.
- Etc

So, I would love to have this tool:

[image: Show on map]

1. Have the picture open in any gallery app or file browser
2. Press the Share button
3. Press "Show on map"
4. (The first time choose what map app you want to open with)
5. The map app you selected opens on the right coordinates

Requirements:

- Free, ideally open source
- Compatible with at least the default gallery and Google Maps, ideally more
- Lightweight

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want that the addon work with **every** gallery/image-viewer that has "send-to"? The goal "show photo(s) in a map" could be met with specialized gallery apps that have a "show in map" function.

Comment: @k3b: The reason is that I want to be able to use whatever gallery app I prefer. I don't want to be tied to a particular gallery app just because it happens to have this feature.

Comment: I have added the idea of this ticket to https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/issues/78. I donot know if there is anybody who wants to implement this as a Lightweight standalone feature or integrate into my gallery app. If you find an app that can do it or if you find somebody who wants to implement it please let us know here